# How to get the list of printers in java?

Tags: java, printers

How can I display all the printers installed on the device in `Java`?

So far to find my printer I use :

```
    PrintUtility.findPrintService(printer); //Selects any printer with the name provided
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, null);
    //System.out.println("Printers avialiable are " + services);
    System.out.println("Printer Selected " + services[Printerinx]);
```

But I wish to display in the console, all printers. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Assuming the lookupPrintServices returns all printers, to display the array user Arrays.toString(services)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
```

This returns PrintService[], filled with all printers the system has available.